# Cannot add Android Platform in Phonegap

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ant, phonegap-build

I want to create Android apps using Phonegap. I have installed nodejs, phonegap, cordova, eclipse and everything. But while trying to add android platform i am getting this error. After a lot of searching some says add 'ant' path to system variables. I have done that. But may be i did wrong. Tried a lot of times. Not working. Here the error i am getting while trying to add android platform

```
C:\hello>cordova platform add android
Creating android project...

C:\Users\gijo\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and add
ed to your path.
    at C:\Users\gijo\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:47
:27
    at exithandler (child_process.js:644:7)
    at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:660:5)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:808:12)
Error: C:\Users\gijo\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\create.bat: Command
failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\gijo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cor
dova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)

C:\hello>
```

Comment: Try installing ANT by using https://code.google.com/p/winant/

Comment: I have already tried that. Installed it and added the path to ANT_HOME

Comment: just type ant in command prompt. What does it show ?

Comment: did you added `your ant path\APACHE-ANT-1.9.4\BIN\` to path in system variables
can you show the paths you have added in environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

In order to develop with PhoneGap, and for the system (Windows in your case) to recognize all the directories and all the files you installed, you indeed need to add those libraries to "variables" inside the System Properties.

Make sure you have the right path. For example:

Variable name: JAVA_HOME
Variable value: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_39

Variable name: ANT_HOME
Variable value: C:\Program Files (x86)\WinAnt

Comment: Thanks. Let me try that

Comment: I tried that. But still i am getting the same error. I tried echo'ing the variables. They all are ok. Below is the result I got. Directories are correct.

C:\hello>echo %ANT_HOME%
C:\ant
C:\hello>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_39
@npc

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but solved.The issue related with `ant` path.Set the path in system variables by this way.
goto Environmentvariables->system variables->select `path` variable click edit and add your `ant` path after a semicolon.

Comment: Ok. Let me try that one.

Comment: Tried that one. Still not working. Its the same error.

Comment: Did you use java 64 bit or 32 bit?.Make sure that your OS and java have same bit version(if your os 64 bit your java must be 64 bit).

Comment: I am having 64 bit processor. The java I installed is also 64bit